# Check that complex charts being compatible

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces by Rick Miranda. I let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $U$ be any open subset of $X$. Then I define $\phi_{U} (x,y) = x+iy$ from $U$ to $\mathbb{C}$, being a complex chart on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then it wants me to prove that any two charts defined like this are compatible with each other. 
 Then I first try to use Cauchy-Riemann Equation. I have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$, $\frac{\partial v}{x} = 0$, and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 1$ And this means that the chart satisfies Cauchy-Riemann Equation, and since all four partial derivatives are continuous, then this means that $\phi_{U}(x,y)$ is holomorphic for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
 Then on the book, the definition of being compatible is that we let $\phi_{1}: U_{1} \rightarrow V_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}: U_{2} \rightarrow V_{2}$ be two complex charts on $X$. We say that $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ are compatible if either $U_{1} \cap U_{2} = \emptyset$, or $\phi_{2} \circ \phi_{1}^{-1}: \phi_{1} (U_{1} \cap U_{2}) \rightarrow \phi_{2} (U_{1} \cap U_{2})$ is holomorphic. But I'm confused how I should pick my $phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ in my specific context. 
**UPDATE:** Here my $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ will be the same charts. Then I have $$\phi_{2} \circ \phi_{1}^{-1} = x+iy$$ which is holomorphic, since it's just a linear map.

Comment: $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the same map on the overlap, namely the map you called $\phi_U$. Thus $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}$ is the identity as expected.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I updated my post according to your comment.

Comment: Indeed, and you successfully noted why the identity map is holomorphic so  the charts are (holomorphically) compatible. I'd be a bit cautious in calling $\phi_i$ "charts" since this is an abuse of notation; technically they are the *coordinate* half of the charts $(U_i, \phi_i)$ (there's a chance Miranda takes the more literal view of the $U_i$ being part of the data of the $\phi_i$ since the domain is part of the data of a function, but this is nonstandard notation in my experience). Beyond this minor caveat, well done.